# SQL coding convention: Long select statements with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, convention

This is a very basic question, but I haven't found anything online.

Assume I have a large SQL file with hundreds of long select statements like this:

```
SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL UNION
SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL
```

Should the UNION here be at the end, or in the front, like this:

```
SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL 
UNION SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL
```

Comment: `UNION [ALL]` between the `SELECT`s.

Comment: Now, if you try to run either one of those, you will get a syntax error. As long as the UNION keyword is located within two queries that has the same amount of columns it should be fine.

Comment: You didn't find anything by searching 'SQL Server UNION' on Google? Hard to believe. Also you will get your answer by running the query.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath The queries were just examples if they were to be used in the middle of the script. I edited for clarity.

Comment: @dfundako I didn't find anything on SQL coding conventions that indicate that UNION should be at the end or in the front. A co-worker of mine is arguing it should be in the front because it is easier to detect them. I was just wondering what the best practice is.

Comment: Those two queries are identical. The only difference is the formatting which the sql engine doesn't care about. You could just as easily put that whole thing on a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very much a personal style question. Some write:

```
SELECT
id,
name,
dob
FROM PERSON;
```

Some - like me - write:

```
SELECT
  id
, name
, dob
FROM PERSON;
```

A reasoning of mine for doing so (that is debateable), is that you can comment out all columns except the first with just two dashes without having to fiddle around with commas. But probably it's just because I like it so.

For the very same reason, my friend mauro writes:

```
select 42,'Arthur Dent',date '1957-04-22' union all
select 43,'Ford Prefect',date '1900-08-01' union all
select 44,'Tricia McMillan',date '1959-03-07'
;
```

.. And I write:

```
          SELECT 42,'Arthur Dent',DATE '1957-04-22'
UNION ALL SELECT 43,'Ford Prefect',DATE '1900-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 44,'Tricia McMillan',DATE '1959-03-07'
;
```

There is no wrong or right here. I'd just suggest you are consistent - with yourself, and with all people working on the same project as you.

Cheers - 
Marco

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL UNION
SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL
```

or

```
      SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL
UNION SELECT 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', NULL
```

It doesn't matter.

The columns will be named based on the first select.
`UNION` will remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` won't.

Comment: Also UNION merges datasets from all queries, so there should be none at neither the end nor at the begining